# Running python 3 from Windows 10 command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, path, command-prompt

I just got Windows 10 on a new computer and I downloaded python through Anaconda. I'm having trouble getting the windows command line to run python when I enter "python", like I could on windows 8.

I've tried a bunch of stuff with system and user variables but to no avail.

My .exe has the following path: C:\Users[username]\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.6.5-h0c2934d_0\python.exe

How can I access python with the "python" command from anywhere in command prompt?

Comment: You'll need to add it to the PATH. Google a guide, since many exist.

Comment: Try `py` rather than `python`. The executable `py.exe` gets installed in `C:\Windows` so it's always available on your PATH.

Comment: I wasn't adding the path to "path", it's resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to add a path for your system variables do not include the ending of the file such as ".exe" in this case you only want the path leading to the ".exe" such as

"C:\Users[username]\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.6.5-h0c2934d_0\"

Then restart your computer and try again